# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: websitename/Register does not permit cross-origin framing in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone, asp.net-mvc-5

i am working on web project which is working fine on mobile devices, except a registration page on Iphone. My Application is in MVC 5 ASP.NET. Here is the error i am getting in Error Console.

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: WebsiteName/Register does
 not permit cross-origin framing.
```

I have tried [Accepted answer of this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886720/load-denied-by-x-frame-options-http-test-test-net-feedback-createappid-test) but it does not work for me. Please help me how can i resolve out the problem. any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: any kind of help will be appreciated..\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...you can make it fancier, later.

```
// CONTROLLER
[HttpGet]
[XFrameOptionAllowAll]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    var viewModel = new DoSomethingViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}

// ATTRIBUTE
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Additionally...

If you are using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your views, this call inserts SAMEORIGIN back into the headers, and as such, will also force your calls to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try using, in the web.config file include the code

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then include the following code in the global.asax file

```
 protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
 {
       Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
       Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");
 }
```

build the aplication